Recent publication considering Robinson as a finitist
In a recent article Denying Infinity, Erhardt seems to assume that Robinson (the inventor of nonstandard analysis) was a finitist.
Many questions on this site refer to Robinson as a formalist and he typically does not appear on lists of mathematicians that are considered to be finitists (Esenin-Volpin etc), so what does Erhardt mean by referring to him in this way and is his description justified?

Unfortunately, I've no access to Erhardt's paper and thus I cannot discuss the details.
It may be relevant: Abraham Robinson, From a formalist's point of view (1969) with an explicit rejection of "meaningless" infinities of Platonism, distrust in the "pragmatism" of logical positivism, as well as, contra constructivists, the adoption of classical logic.
See page 47:

It is part of the deliberate policy of the formalist to deal with all sorts of infinite totalities as if they were real, and so his everyday mathematics does not differ from that of the platonic realist. Nevertheless it is inconsistent to adhere at the same time both to the Platonist and to the formalist outlook on mathematics. On the other hand, the formalist shares with the various types of constructivists a basic distrust of infinity and, indeed, is more finitistic than most of them. Although he has opted for the classical way of doing mathematics he need not object to certain constructive versions of arithmetic and analysis and may well admit that they are more concrete and possess a greater immediate empirical content.

And see page 49, for the conclusions:

while I do not at present adhere to the positivistic view just outlined I cannot exclude the possibility that I will be persuaded by it some day. Equally the development of “meaningless” infinitistic theories may at some future date become so unsatisfactory to me that I shall be willing to acknowledge the greater intellectual seriousness of some form of constructivism. But I cannot imagine that I shall ever return to the creed of the true Platonist, who sees the world of the actual infinite spread out before him and believes that he can comprehend the incomprehensible.

Thus, the reasonable conclusion is that Robinson adheres to Formalism, but IMO the relevant meaning of "finitism" is more the Finitary Point of View of Hilbert's Program than Ultrafinitsm.
See also J.Dauben, Abraham Robinson: The Creation of Nonstandard Analysis (1995), page 329, wrt "Formalism 64": by 1964 his philosophical views had undergone considerable change [wrt 1950s Platonic realism], which was reflected directly in the title he gave his Jerusalem paper."
Regarding Robinson's statement quoted above referring to "the deliberate policy of the formalist to deal with all sorts of infinite totalities as if they were real [... in] his everyday mathematics ", see the well-known statement of Philip Davis and Reuben Hersh (from page 359 of the 1995 Edition of The Mathematical Experience (1981)):

“The typical working mathematician is a Platonist on weekdays and a Formalist on Sundays.”


An interesting answer although it leaves out the sentence which immediately precedes the part you quoted: "It is part of the deliberate policy of the formalist to deal with all sorts
of infinite totalities as if they were real, and so his everyday mathematics
does not differ from that of the platonic realist."
